# Getting an Applet Viewer to display with my code

Tags: java, applet

I am taking a Java course at the moment and am on Chapter 4 in Java Illuminate 3rd edition. we are working on getting an Applet to display text and or designs and colors. i am working with a macbook and i am doing my coding through TextWrangler and am trying to run my on my terminal, but for some reason after i compile my code i cannot get the Applet display to show. Please see below to see the code the book gives us and they expect us to get an Applet Viewer by running the code, as such, but i cannot find out how to do so.

```
/* Drawing Text
   Anderson, Franceschi
*/


import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawingTextApplet extends JApplet
{
  public void paint( Graphics g )
  {
    super.paint( g );
    g.drawString( "Programming is not", 140, 100 );
    g.drawString( "a spectator sport!", 140, 115 ); //for every new line you add 15 to the Y cord.
  }
}
```

Comment: If you run `appletview.exe` from the command line with `-?`, it will print out the parameter requirements.  What it's looking for is the URL to the HTML page which defines the applet tag for your applet.  You might want to have a read through [Java Applets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) for more details

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

Direct from the [applet](/questions/tagged/applet) tag [info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  Take particular note of the multi-line comments.

> ### Applet 'Hello World' Example
>
> This example requires the Java Development Kit installed. Visit Java SE Downloads for the latest JDK.

```
/* <!-- Defines the applet element used by the appletviewer. -->
<applet code='HelloWorld' width='200' height='100'></applet> */
import javax.swing.*;

/** An 'Hello World' Swing based applet.

To compile and launch:
prompt> javac HelloWorld.java
prompt> appletviewer HelloWorld.java  */
public class HelloWorld extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        // Swing operations need to be performed on the EDT.
        // The Runnable/invokeAndWait(..) ensures that happens.
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // the crux of this simple applet
                getContentPane().add( new JLabel("Hello World!") );
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use other Swing tools instead of applets. You don't have to go through the hassle of finding an applet viewer or possibly changing the security settings for Java if you do; applets are also pretty outdated.

If you changed your program to something like this...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawingTextPanel extends JPanel
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Programming is not", 140, 100);
        g.drawString("a spectator sport!", 140, 115);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new DrawingTextPanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

...you'll get the same display that you would using an applet. Similar to how you do your painting in the `paint` method with an applet, you would do it in the `paintComponent` method in this case.

Comment: `paintComponent` shouldn't be `public`, you never want anybody else to be able to call it.  Nitpick, but I wouldn't be creating a frame within the constructor of the panel, this basically amounts to just extending directly from a `JFrame`, it reduces the re-use to 0.  Instead, create the frame in the `main` method and add the panel to it ;)

Comment: that makes a lot of sense and i definitely can see how this would be much simpler. but.. this is a class i am taking and for the classes sake i should probably learn how to use these Applets, because i will be graded and tested on it. Do you know how i can get the output for this code using my terminal?

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're right, it should be `protected`. And your suggestions make sense, though I was simply suggesting an easier way to show graphical output for the OP. Thanks though.

Comment: @Tnt I have nothing against your overall answer, I'm just be nit picky ;)

Comment: @ElliottAmador I have next to no experience with Terminal, but without using it you can probably edit a .txt file, enter `<APPLET CODE = "[path-to-class-file].class" WIDTH=[width] HEIGHT=[height]></APPLET>`, save it as .html, and somehow run it from terminal that way (though if you have to do it all from Terminal, you should probably learn how to edit, save, and run files from it that way). (You can replace `[width]` and `[height]` with reasonable values.)

Comment: @ElliottAmador Quite honestly I don't see why you would be tested on how to display an applet; you should probably ask your instructor for clarification. MadProgrammer's comment above could also be useful.