# How to run Java applets in browser (with CMD)

Tags: java, applet

I know, no one uses applets now, but My Undergrad degree still have this in the syllabus!!

This is my `HelloWorld.java` file code

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

This is my `Hello.html` file code

```html
<html>
    <body>
        Here is the output of my program:
        <applet code="HelloWorld.class" width="150" height="25"></applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both the files are saved to desktop.

This is what I did:

1. Open CMD
2. Type `cd desktop`
3. Type `javac HelloWorld.java`
4. Open Hello.html file in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Microsoft Edge

None of the browser runs the applet!!  Normal Java (AWT) programs are running using CMD but not applet.

JDK & JRE version I am using is jdk1.8.0_201 & jre1.8.0_201 respectively.

Comment:  You can't.  The short and long answer is, an applet is expected to run within a Applet container.  Since none of the current version of browsers support the plugin, and the plugin itself is deprecated and was removed in Java 9, I would say you up the creek without a paddle and your course should get of it's lazy backside and update it's syllabus. Now. Having whinged about all that, there is a "applet browser", but it's been so long since I've had to care, I don't recall what it's called.  Go hunting in the JDK's bin directory

Comment: Please refer the teacher / college to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the commands below:

```
/*
<html>
<applet code="HelloWorld.class" CodeBase="" width=300 height=400></applet>
</html>
*/
```

save this as "HelloWorld.html"

```
c:\>javac HelloWorld.java
c:\>appletviewer HelloWorld.html
```

Comment: The HTML can be included directly in the `.java` source code as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330042/getting-an-applet-viewer-to-display-with-my-code/31335531#31335531).